# FileNotFoundException in Filesystem.php Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working in a Laravel Tutorial and i have this method in my NoticesController.php

```
public function confirm(PrepareNoticeRequest $request, Guard $auth)
    {
        $data = $request->all() + [
            'name'  => $auth->user()->name,
            'email' => $auth->user()->email,
        ];

        $template = view()->file(app_path('Http/Templates/dmca.blade.php'), $data);

        return $template;
    }
```

in my route.php

```
Route::get('notices/create/confirm', 'NoticesController@confirm');
```

and I have a file inside app/Http/Templates/dmca.blade.php
However I got this error

```
FileNotFoundException in Filesystem.php line 36:
File does not exist at path /home/vagrant/Projects/dmca-app/app/Http/Templates/dmca.blade.php
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: First things first, can you confirm that the file actually exists in `/home/vagrant/Projects/dmca-app/app/Http/Templates/` (emphasizing the entire absolute path) ?

Comment: Hi BassemDy, how can I do that? For example in Laravel 4 I know you can try with File::exists(), however in Laravel 5 I am not sure about it.

Comment: browse there in your filesystem out side of laraval - are you on a mac? open your terminal and paste

cat /home/vagrant/Projects/dmcaapp/app/Http/Templates/dmca.blade.php

if it doesn't exist terminal will tell you, if it does, it will show code

Comment: You're right my file is not in Http folder, I put it on there and everything work fine. Thanks a lot BassemDy

Comment: Thanks picus I found the problem, my bad.